# How to obtain expected execution time and worst case for algorithms with infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, infinite-loop, execution-time

I have a one doubt about expected execution time and worst case executio time of algorithms, I was think a simple algorithm but this contain a loop infinite and I don't know about to explain that expected execution time?. I could always determine the time to algorithms with stop conditions.

This is my example (I just know, that more than n/2 can give true):

```
while (true)
{
  int i = random(0,n-1);
  bool e = decision(i); //Θ(n)
  if (e==true)
     return i;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  What sort of explanation are you trying to produce?  One source of confusion for me is that you've tagged this with "big-o", but made no reference to complexity in the posting.  Rather, the posting deals with execution time, which is a very practical concept, rather than the asymptotic scaling limit.

Comment: Is `decisions` probabilistic? What is the likelihood it returns true? Are there certain values for which it is true? In the current form, you can't say anything about the expected runtime.

Comment: @Prune, Hi, you're right, add something more to the text. I understand that the worst case refers to the Big (O) notation, but I have confusion as to execution time and asymptotic notation, what relationships do they have?

Comment: @Skam, yes, you are right, but I'm not sure about probability. I just know, that more than n / 2 can give true.

Comment: does random mean you're sampling uniformly at random?

Comment: @Skam, yes, sure, everything has the same probability of being selected.

Comment: @GMs: You should look up an explanation of "big-O" notation; there are several good ones on this site, as well as a good one on WIkipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected execution time is O(n).

With probability `p >= 1/2`, the first `i` will give `decision(i) == true`, so the loop will terminate after one call to `decision`.

Let `q = 1 - p` be the probability that it did not happen.
Then, with probability `q * p`, the second `i` will give `decision(i) == true`, so the loop will terminate after two calls to `decision`.

Similarly, with probability `q^2 * p`, the third `i` will give `decision(i) == true`, so the loop will terminate after three calls to `decision`, and so on.

By taking the sum, we have the expected number of calls to `decision` as
`1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + ...`.
As `q <= 1/2`, the sum is at most `1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...` which has an upper limit of `2`.
So, the expected number of calls is limited by `2`.

In total, as each call to `decision` takes `O(n)` time, the expected time to run is `O(2*n)` which is still `O(n)` since `2` is a constant.

Comment: It's easy to solve exactly: the number of iterations E satisfies E = 1 + (1-p)E, so E=1/p.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yeah, that would be a good answer! But I didn't think of it, since my reading of the question somehow suggested I should stick to the basics.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `decision` has probability 1/2? The OP says nothing about the conditions under which `decision` will return true.

Comment: @JimMischel The phrase "I just know, that more than n/2 can give true" is explained so in comments. If you have a better way to phrase it (and I bet you do), please consider editing it into the question.

Comment: That's not the way I interpreted that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It seems dependant on the probabilty that decision ends up being true.
So in this case decision takes n steps.
Which means that the runtime is O(n),
Now we take the probability of decision being true, assume 50%, that means on avarage we need to 2n steps per loop(  sum(prob^x*n) , x=0..infinity ,prob=0.5).
Eventhough O increases by the decision probability, the multiplication is still linearly bound to the change of "decision" being true, and therefore stil O(n).